# How to prevent php files from creating folder in parent directories?

Tags: php, directory, mkdir, subdirectory

For example, I have a Parent directory and a Folder inside:

> mysite.com/Parent_Folder/A_Folder/File.php

File.php contains the following code:

```
<?php
mkdir('/Parent_Folder/A_New_Folder', 0777, true);
```

I want to **prevent the file from creating folders in parent directories**. How do I **restrict** this?

However, **creating folders in the same directory must be allowed**, for example the following code must work:

```
<?php
mkdir('A_New_Folder_in_Current_Directory', 0777, true);
```

which will result in:

> mysite.com/Parent_Folder/A_Folder/A_New_Folder_in_Current_Directory

Comment: Do you get the folder name by input, or you want to limit this file in general?

Comment: Why not check if mkdir() is trying to create the folder in the parent or current directory before creating it?

Comment: @birraa The system allows users to input php code, so basically the users are creating the files and not me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Trondro Mullingan !

You can try clean '../../' you can test this:

file.php:

```
<?php

   // from post
   $new_folder = '../../A_New_Folder_in_Current_Directory';
   // you need removed the ../../

   $new_folder_clean = str_replace('../../','',$new_folder);

   //now you create the folder together file.php file.

   mkdir($new_folder_clean, 0777, true);

?>
```

Also you can set a actually folder var to concatenate for make children folder.